# Read value from string which looks like jSon format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

I have cookie value stored in following format

> {stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}

and i need to read following values of

```
necessary
preferences
statistics
marketing
```

Not sure how to to read values correctly, i tried following code assuming it is jSON format

```
        Cookies.get('CookieConsent')

        //Parse the cookie to Object

        cookieval = Cookies.get('CookieConsent');
        console.log(cookieval);

        console.log("Necessary: " + Boolean(cookieval.necessary));
        console.log("Prefrences: " + Boolean(cookieval.preferences));
        console.log("Statistics: " + Boolean(cookieval.statistics));
        console.log("Marketing: " + Boolean(cookieval.marketing));
```

But this code always returns false.

I use following Jquery to read Cookie values https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have JSON format - you have something closer to JS object literal notation, except that it's a string rather than JS code, so can't use `JSON.parse` unfortunately.

If the values don't have commas or colons, you can `split` the string by commas and `reduce` into an object:

```js
const input = `{stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}`;
const obj = input
  .slice(1, input.length - 1)
  .split(',')
  .reduce((obj, str) => {
    const [key, val] = str.split(':');
    obj[key] = val;
    return obj;
  }, {});
console.log(obj);
```

`eval` is another option, but that's unsafe.

Comment: Run the code snippet - just access `obj.preferences` or whichever property you need

Comment: Thanks  console.log(obj.necessary);

Answer (score 2):

Wrap this string by `(` and `)`. Then parse like as display follow

*Attention!* But you need be ensure `input` string (which received from cookie) not contains bad code. Such as unknown injected function. In this case, the function will be executed on client browser, with access to private data (cookie, localStorage, data from html-forms).

```js
const input = "{stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}"
const object = eval("(" + input + ")");
alert(object.necessary);
```

Comment: This method works reliably, buy not secure. Method from other answer works only with simple input string, but is secure.

Answer (score 1):

What about massaging the string into proper JSON, parsing it into a JSON Object, and using the fields from there?

It's less stable in that changes to the input string may break the function, but it is secure in that it's calling JSON.parse() rather than eval().

```js
   function reformatCookieInput(inputString) {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/'/g, "");  //global strip out single quotes currently wrapping stamp
    inputString = inputString.replace(/,/g, `", "`); //global replace commas with wrapped commas
    inputString = inputString.replace(/:/g, `":"`); //same idea with colons
    inputString = inputString.replace("{", `{"`); //rewrap start of JSON string
    inputString = inputString.replace("}", `"}`); //rewrap end of JSON string

    return inputString;
}

const input = `{stamp:'HMzWoJn8V4ZkdRN1DduMHLhS3dKiDDr6VoXCjjeuDMO2w6V+n2CcOg==',necessary:true,preferences:true,statistics:true,marketing:false,ver:1}`;

const properJSONObject = JSON.parse(reformatCookieInput(input));
console.log(properJSONObject);
```